# Mysql case when group by foreach row

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

Database products_api:

```
SHOPID PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_CODE  
1      prod_name1     SKU1  
2      prod_name2     SKU1  
3      prod_name3     SKU1
```

I wanna group by PRODUCT_CODE and get PRODUCT_NAME for every SHOPID;
My code :

```
SELECT case when SHOPID = 1 then PRODUCT_NAME end as shopid1,  
case when SHOPID = 2 then PRODUCT_NAME end as shopid2,  
case when SHOPID = 3 then PRODUCT_NAME end as shopid3,PRODUCT_CODE  
FROM products_api   
GROUP BY PRODUCT_CODE
```

The result should be one line with :

```
shopid1    shopid2    shopid3    PRODUCT_CODE  
prod_name1 prod_name2 prod_name3 SKU1
```

but result is one row with :

```
shopid1    shopid2    shopid3    PRODUCT_CODE  
prod_name1                       SKU1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it working. Just need to add `MAX` aggregate function around the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT MAX(case when SHOPID = 1 then PRODUCT_NAME end) as shopid1,  
       MAX(case when SHOPID = 2 then PRODUCT_NAME end) as shopid2,  
       MAX(case when SHOPID = 3 then PRODUCT_NAME end) as shopid3,
       PRODUCT_CODE  
FROM products_api   
GROUP BY PRODUCT_CODE
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e930b5/1)

Comment: I'd think `GROUP_CONCAT` is better, since the names are strings.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru This depends on the requirements. The OP clearly states he/she wants a separate column for each `SHOPID` value.

Comment: @GrempelsGabriel Could have used `MIN` as well. We just need an aggregation function that will operate on `VARCHAR` and will return the field value.